# Delphi #IF(DEBUG) equivalent?

Tags: delphi, compiler-directives

Is there a Delphi equivalent of the C# #if(DEBUG) compiler directive?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Use this:

```
{$IFDEF DEBUG}
...
{$ENDIF}
```

Comment: And make sure the project options define DEBUG. I think only the newer Delphi (D2007 and up?) versions set it by default for a debug build.

Comment: For older versions you can use {$IFOPT D+}.  'D' is the compiler option symbol for "Compile with Debug Info".  'D+' indicates that what follows should only be compiled if that option is *ON*.

Comment: For portability of the more readable {$IFDEF DEBUG} you could of course include something like {$IFOPT C+}{$DEFINE DEBUG}{$ENDIF} in a standard defines include file (in the sections relating to versions of Delphi that don't auto-define DEBUG for you.  Note however that this "auto-define" is not always reliable.  DEBUGINFO I think is auto-defined but DEBUG is only defined if you leave the default conditionals for the DEBUG build as they are (they include DEBUG as a "factory" setting, but this can and may be removed.  i.e. It's not a "built-in" definition when building with Debug Info on.

Comment: @Deltics: IFOPT C+ is true when assertions are on, do you mean IFOPT D+?

Comment: @Deltics: thats antincorrect, $IFDEF DEBUG is with us since ~1990

Comment: @user205376 - Set project options to "Debug", then remove the DEBUG conditional define.  Or, turn on "Debug Info" but *fail* to add a DEBUG conditional define.  Either way, the result is: A build with debug info but code enclosed in $ifdef DEBUG will NOT be compiled.  The convention of adding a default define of a DEBUG compiler conditional symbol may have been with us since 1990 (but Delphi only since 1995, so how/if/why it perpetuates the convention is entirely up for grabs and clearly the presence of a DEBUG define is NOT connected to the presence of Debug Information in the build).

Comment: @David - yes.  my bad.  I guess the mistake was easily spotted tho :)

Answer (score 9):

DebugHook is set if an application is running under the IDE debugger.  Not the same as a compiler directive but still pretty useful.  For example:

```
ReportMemoryLeaksOnShutdown := DebugHook <> 0; // show memory leaks when debugging
```

Answer (score 8):

Apart from what lassevk said, you can also use a few other methods of compiler-evaluation (since Delphi 6, I believe) :

```
{$IF NOT DECLARED(SOME_SYMBOL)} 
  // Mind you : The NOT above is optional
{$ELSE}
{$IFEND}
```

To check if the compiler has this feature, use :

```
 {$IFDEF CONDITIONALEXPRESSIONS}
```

There are several uses for this.

For example, you could check the version of the RTL; From the Delphi help :

> You can use RTLVersion in $IF
>   expressions to test the runtime
>   library   version level independently
>   of the compiler version level.
>   Example:  {$IF RTLVersion >= 16.2} ...
>   {$IFEND}

Also, the compiler version itself can be checked, again from the code:

> CompilerVersion is assigned a value by
>   the compiler when   the system unit is
>   compiled.  It indicates the revision
>   level of the   compiler features /
>   language syntax, which may advance
>   independently of   the RTLVersion. 
>   CompilerVersion can be tested in $IF
>   expressions and   should be used
>   instead of testing for the VERxxx
>   conditional define.   Always test for
>   greater than or less than a known
>   revision level.   It's a bad idea to
>   test for a specific revision level.

Another thing I do regularly, is define a symbol when it's not defined yet (nice for forward-compatiblity), like this :

```
 {$IF NOT DECLARED(UTF8String)}
 type
   UTF8String = type AnsiString;
 {$IFEND}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: @user205376 : Thanks for the sharp eye, I fixed the typo.

Answer (score 3):

These control directives are available:

```
{$IFDEF}
{$ELSE}
{$ENDIF}
{$IFNDEF} //if *not* defined
```

and they can be used as shown here:

```
procedure TfrmMain.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  {$IFDEF MY_CONDITIONAL}
  ShowMessage('my conditional IS defined!');
  {$ELSE}
  ShowMessage('my conditional is NOT defined!');
  {$ENDIF}

  {$IFNDEF MY_CONDITIONAL}
  ShowMessage('My conditional is explicitly NOT defined');
  {$ENDIF}
end;
```

Comment: You forgot {$IFOPT}, which can be used to directly test for compiler settings.

{$IFOPT D+}  // DEBUG INFO ON
{$IFOPT C+}  // ASSERTIONS ENABLED

etc